# Firebase Dynamic Links security

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I’m using Firebase dynamic Link in my app to share information between users ( like post id )

the URL with post id is something like : https://myapp.web.app/opkzpeokzkpk12pokfze

the generated short dynamic link is :  https://myapp.page.link/abcd

everything work fine, when user click on the dynamic link we are able to decode the postId

Now I’m receiving this email from google :

**We’re writing to let you know that your Firebase Dynamic Links (FDL) project(s) do not have configuration to prevent phishing. Please specify the allowed URLs that Dynamic Links in your projects can redirect to.
Specifying a URL allowlist prevents third parties from using your API key to create Dynamic Links that redirect from your FDL domain to sites not on the allowlist.**

can I use this ?

**Allowed domain** : myapp.web.app

**Regular expression preview** : `^https{0,1}:\/\/myapp.web\.app([\/#\?].*){0,1}$`

my app is used on production and I’m not sure about this change ?

can someone suggest if this URL is correct or which URLs can use ?

Comment: to be honest I don't remember exactly what I did, but I receive suggestion in  Dynamic Links view like " To increase the security of your project, we have automatically configured allowed domains for your Dynamic Links. Learn more", so I click on review domain and regexp is already filled, so I accept, suggestion is "^https{0,1}:\/\/myapp\.app([\/#\?].*){0,1}$" --> hop this help

Comment: In my case this regex is already there, but I want to know how you configure AASA file to now allow any other path to be open in app. As In firebase it generate AASA file automatically without no path to restrict. Please advice.